# Почему операторы ввода вывода необходима перегружать через дружественные функции?

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Знаю, что необходимо перегружать через дружественные функции, но не до конца понимаю почему.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/237074/6944845

Answer (score 2):

Можно и не через дружественные, если есть возможность доступа к тому, что выводится.

Дружественность нужна для удобства, непосредственного обращения к закрытым членам-данным класса, или если доступа к выводимой информации через открытый интерфейс нет.

Comment: Если есть поле класса, которое необходимо видеть пользователю в потоке вывода, то невозможность получить его значение из программы - странный дизайн. Если согласится с этим, оператор вывода не должен быть другом.

Comment: оффтоп. я в джаве парсил вывод toString что бы получить приватные поля без рефлексии. так что иногда полезен и такой дизайн =)

Comment: А можете объяснить необходимость перегрузки операторов ввода и вывода через внешние функции?

Comment: Проблем... :) Если это будет функция-член, то *первым аргументом* будет сам объект класса, так что вы не сможете написать что-то типа `cout << x`, а только `x >> cout` :) И в цепочку их не свяжете... Неудобно, правда?